# How to configure second level cache in Hibernate 4.3

Tags: java, hibernate, second-level-cache

I have read post related with this but not get any answer working for me.
I am configuring `second level cache` in `Hibernate v4.3.` And I have used `MySQL 5.0`

I have written following elements in `hibernate.cfg.xml`

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory</property>
```

I have annotated my Entity class for cache as follows

```
@Entity 

@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
public class Employee { ....}
```

Following exception is shown when run

> ```
> INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
> Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.cache.spi.RegionFactory]
>     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:233)
>     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:197)
>     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:178)
>     at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:295)
>     at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2442)
>     at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2438)
>     at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1855)
>     at com.example.hibernate.Hibernate4Main.main(Hibernate4Main.java:32)
> Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: could not instantiate RegionFactory [org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory]
>     at org.hibernate.cache.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator.initiateService(RegionFactoryInitiator.java:101)
>     at org.hibernate.cache.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator.initiateService(RegionFactoryInitiator.java:46)
>     at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:83)
>     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:223)
>     ... 7 more
> Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException: Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory] as strategy [org.hibernate.cache.spi.RegionFactory]
>     at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.selectStrategyImplementor(StrategySelectorImpl.java:128)
>     at org.hibernate.cache.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator.initiateService(RegionFactoryInitiator.java:87)
>     ... 10 more
> ```

I have seen than there are different cache providers for `Hibernate v3` like `EhCacheProvoider`. All are in `org.hibernate.cache` package.
But for `Hibernate 4.3` there are only 3 classes as `RegionFactory.class` and other two are of `exception`.

**1. What is wrong with above code?**

**2. What are major changes made for Second level cache configuration in Hibernate 4.3?**

Comment: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#performance-cache

Answer (score 6):

I solved this for my configuration. Viewing the "effective pom" for my project had shown:

```
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>        
    ...
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    ...
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

along with most of my other dependencies.

Copying that hibernate-ehcache dependency into my actual project pom file added a second entry for it outside of the `<dependencyManagement/>` tag and that solved my problem. I had thought that because it was already included in the effective pom I didn't need to add it but apparently that is not the case for hibernate-ehcache as it seems to be for other packages.

Comment: Guy, you are magician. I also assumed that it is already included

Answer (score 3):

Your pom.xml file should look like below

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.7.Final</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
                    <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

and Your hibernate.cfg.xml should contain the following configuration

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory</property>
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer this - http://architects.dzone.com/articles/hibernate-4-and-ehcache-higher

add hibernate-ehcache jar to your project, that will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem before. I added slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar to the project and fixed this problem. I was using Hibernate 4.3.5.